# I need a Help in Creating a Search Engine in Java

Tags: java, parsing, file, search, document

My Problem is, I am goin to develop a site where every one uploads the doc file, txt files etc. Now here I need a component which actually pasre the file for some Key words and mainatin the index of that. And also that Index should be updated based on the Strutured data as well, like document can actively viewable and so forth. When another user try to look that list of document based on some key word and some strutured data as mentioned earlier, user should find the list quickly. And it should support the Multi Language. We have an alogorthim in place, but we need an open source API for reading the file indexing the file with Unstrutured data based on key word. Can any one can help in this.

Answer (score 2):

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) with [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is the best open source solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial task, so why reinvent when other people have already done that: try [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/).

Comment: No actually we are not planning for reinvent on this, I have just mentioned some part techinical aspect of the parser we are looking. We are in study , which one is better , Still not finalized it yet.We dont want every thing in place, we just need some specific part of search to our business.